# g++ output: file not recognized: File format not recognized

Tags: gcc, build, g++, makefile

I am trying to build program with multiple files for the first time.
I have never had any problem with compliling program with main.cpp only.
With following commands, this is the result:

```
$ g++ -c src/CNumber.cpp src/CNumber.h -o src/CNumber.o
$ g++ -c src/CExprPart.cpp src/CExprPart.h -o src/CExprPart.o
$ g++ -c src/CExpr.cpp src/CExpr.h -o src/CExpr.o
$ g++ -c src/main.cpp -o src/main.o
$ g++ src/CNumber.o src/CExprPart.o src/CExpr.o src/main.o -o execprogram
src/CNumber.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What could cause such error and what should I do with it?
Using Linux Mint with gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1).
Thank you

Comment: It's a bit weird to include header files on the compilation command lines like that.

Comment: You are right, this is the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
 g++ -c src/CNumber.cpp src/CNumber.h -o src/CNumber.o
```

You shouldn't "compile" .h files. Doing so will create precompiled header files, which are not used to create an executable.
The above should simply be

```
 g++ -c src/CNumber.cpp -o src/CNumber.o
```

Similar for compiling the other .cpp files

Comment: So, as far I understand it, builder is able to find these header files by itself due to #include directives, right?

Comment: @user2489350 Yes. Depending on where they are located. You can specify additional paths to search for #include files with the -I argument to gcc/g++

Answer (score 35):

I ran into this error in building something - it turned out to be due to a previous build failing while compiling a source file to an .o file - that .o file was incomplete or corrupted, so when I tried another build it gave this error on that file.

The solution was to just delete the .o file (or run `make clean`, if you have a makefile with that target).

Comment: Solved my issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting all of the following files in one directory:

example.cpp:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

#include "my_functions.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << getGreeting() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

my_functions.cpp:

```
#include<string>
using namespace std;

string getGreeting()
{
    return "Hello world";
}
```

my_functions.h:

```
#ifndef _MY_FUNCTIONS_H
#define _MY_FUNCTIONS_H

#include<string>
using namespace std;

string getGreeting();

#endif
```

Then issue these commands:

```
$ g++ example.cpp my_functions.cpp -o myprogram
~/c++_programs$ ./myprogram
Hello world
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. It builds fine. If I use just ./myprogram instead of your second line, I get correct output (hello world)