# G++ include .rc files from cmd

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, cmd, g++

I've made a simple WIN32 project using resources (.rc files).

When I compile with code::blocks the dialog box displays,
but when compiling with g++ from cmd it doesn't.

Trying to include the .rc as an argument to g++ results in this:
`main.rc: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

How do I include the .rc file to g++ in cmd?

Edit:
I tried with windres doing:
`windres main.rc -o res.o`
`g++ -c win_main.cpp resource.h -o source.o`
`g++ -o Executable res.o source.o`

I get the same error but with `main.o` instead of `main.rc` not recognized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference between MS resource tools and GNU tools is that MS RC generates'.res' files in a special binary resource format, which can be passed directly to MS links, while GNU linker LD only supports '.o' (the same as'.obj') format. So As the answer of @SoronelHaetir, you need to use the windres:
`windres main.rc -o res.o`

What else I want to point out is You shouldn't "compile" .h files. Doing so will create precompiled header files, which are not used to create an executable, then cause the `xxx.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized`. Builder is able to find these header files by itself due to #include directives. See the similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126384/g-output-file-not-recognized-file-format-not-recognized).

Comment: Removing the header file as an argment to g++ did the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

.rc files aren't fed to gcc, they have to be processed by windres (the gcc equivalent of MS' rc.exe), you use windres to create a .o file from the .rc and then feed that .o to gcc (or ld) as part of your final link stage.

```
windres my_file.rc my_file.o
gcc -o my_final <other parameters> my_file.o
```

There are other potential arguments to windres, look at the man page for details.